# How long should a checksum be?

Tags: checksum, crc

TCP segments include a checksum field of 16-bits and so do IP datagrams and UDP packets. However at the link layer, the CRC checksum is only 4 bits (for 802.3 and 802.4).

On the extreme part of the spectrum, only computing a parity bit might yield a lot of false-positive, where a packet looks valid but in fact is not, because an even number of bits have been altered. On the other hand, having a 16-bit checksum when only 4 bits would suffice is a waste of memory/bandwidth/money.

How do you evaluate how many bits your checksum should be?

PS: I have taken the internet stack as an example, but this applies to any protocol/software really.

PS2: I am not sure which forum to use.

Comment: the crc checksum in 802.3 is four bytes CRC of 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

First, a quick nomenclature correction - checksums and CRCs are 2 different approaches trying to solve the same problem: detect bit errors occurred during data transmission in noisy channels. In general CRCs are more powerful detecting errors at the expense of more complexity.

Selecting the right error detection scheme requires some knowledge about the channel (e.g. error probability) and its noise characteristics (e.g. impulsive, bursty). There are papers out there where this problem is analyzed in detail and some guidance is given in how to select the error detection method. I suggest you trying this introductory presentation as a starting point:

http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/pubs/KoopmanCRCWebinar9May2012.pdf

It will give you a better understanding of the complexity of this beautiful area and provide you some links to other learning materials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a good CRC or hash function that makes good use of the bits, and assuming that the expected sources of corruption do not have some unusual characteristics that invalidate the first assumption, then you can simply set an acceptable probability of a false positive, and get the number of bits from that.  Or compute the probability from the bits and see if you're comfortable with that.  The probability is:

p = 2<sup>-n</sup>

where *n* is the number of bits in the check value.  That is the probability that an *n*-bit check value on some random data will accidentally match the *n*-bit check value on some other set of data.